# Finding percentage difference of daily data compared to monthly means in R

Tags: r, diff

I want to find how much daily temperatures differ to a specified monthly mean at various locations. I was thinking of having this a percentage difference value. For example, the specified monthly mean is 20 and I have some days that are 15(-25%), 25(+25%) and 10 (-50%).

The only way I can think of is to create a repeating column with the monthly means at each location and then using the diff function or a percentage difference formula calculate the difference between the columns. I was wondering if there is a more elegant and easier way to do this that would be suitable for big data?

I then want to use this daily trend or difference and apply this to a different set of monthly means to break this into daily data. For example, say the monthly mean is 10 and I have a few day trends that are +25% (12.5), -50% (5) and -25% (7.5). Again, is there an elegant or easier way to this?

Any help would be appreciated. I am still quite new to R!

Here is some sample data:

## Sample data

```
date <- c("2009-01-01", "2009-01-02", "2009-01-03", "2009-01-04","2009-01-05",
          "2009-01-01", "2009-01-02", "2009-01-03", "2009-01-04","2009-01-05",
          "2009-01-01", "2009-01-02", "2009-01-03", "2009-01-04","2009-01-05")

location <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
           "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
           "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")

daily_temp <- c(10, 12, 12, 9, 8,
               13, 14, 18, 8, 11,
               14, 18, 20, 16, 17)

data_daily <- cbind(date, location, daily_temp)

mean_monthly <- c(12, 14, 16)

location_monthly <- c("A", "B", "C")

data_monthly <- cbind(mean_monthly, location_monthly)
```

Comment: Side comment - I don't think percentage different makes sense for temperatures (except maybe for Kelvin or Rankine!).  Might make more sense to use standard deviation, or mean/median average difference, etc...

Comment: Hi Jim, I have edited the question to include some sample data. The temperature data I have is in degrees Celsius. Percentage difference is the first thing that came to mind but I could look at using standard deviation or mean difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your source data in the correct format for analysis

```
df.daily <- as.data.frame( data_daily, stringsAsFactors = F)
df.monthly <- as.data.frame( data_monthly, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

### tidyverse

```
library( tidyverse )

df.daily <- as.data.frame( data_daily, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
df.monthly <- as.data.frame( data_monthly, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

df.daily %>% 
  left_join( df.monthly, by = c( "location" = "location_monthly" ) ) %>%
  mutate( daily_temp = as.numeric( daily_temp ) ) %>%
  mutate( mean_monthly = as.numeric( mean_monthly ) ) %>%
  mutate( delta_temp = ( daily_temp - mean_monthly ) / mean_monthly )

#          date location daily_temp mean_monthly  delta_temp
# 1  2009-01-01        A         10           12 -0.16666667
# 2  2009-01-02        A         12           12  0.00000000
# 3  2009-01-03        A         12           12  0.00000000
# 4  2009-01-04        A          9           12 -0.25000000
# 5  2009-01-05        A          8           12 -0.33333333
# 6  2009-01-01        B         13           14 -0.07142857
# 7  2009-01-02        B         14           14  0.00000000
# 8  2009-01-03        B         18           14  0.28571429
# 9  2009-01-04        B          8           14 -0.42857143
# 10 2009-01-05        B         11           14 -0.21428571
# 11 2009-01-01        C         14           16 -0.12500000
# 12 2009-01-02        C         18           16  0.12500000
# 13 2009-01-03        C         20           16  0.25000000
# 14 2009-01-04        C         16           16  0.00000000
# 15 2009-01-05        C         17           16  0.06250000
```

### data.table

```
#less readable but usually faster , especially on larger datasets
library( data.table )

setDT( df.monthly )[, mean_monthly := as.numeric( mean_monthly )][setDT( df.daily )[, daily_temp := as.numeric( daily_temp )], on = c( "location_monthly==location" )][, delta_temp := ( daily_temp - mean_monthly ) / mean_monthly ][]
```

### benchmarks

data.table has a slight advantage

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark( tidyverse = {df.daily %>% 
    left_join( df.monthly, by = c( "location" = "location_monthly" ) ) %>%
    mutate( daily_temp = as.numeric( daily_temp ) ) %>%
    mutate( mean_monthly = as.numeric( mean_monthly ) ) %>%
    mutate( delta_temp = ( daily_temp - mean_monthly ) / mean_monthly )},
    data.table = {setDT(df.monthly)[, mean_monthly := as.numeric( mean_monthly )][setDT(df.daily)[, daily_temp := as.numeric( daily_temp )], on = c( "location_monthly==location" )][, delta_temp := ( daily_temp - mean_monthly ) / mean_monthly ][]},
    times = 100)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr            min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
# tidyverse  2.318527 2.408303 2.579056 2.454999 2.513293 13.104373   100
# data.table 1.515959 1.590221 1.669511 1.643545 1.702141  2.345037   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Wimpel's response, here are some ways to summarize location variance.

```
df.combo <-
  df.daily%>% 
  left_join( df.monthly, by = c( "location" = "location_monthly" ) ) %>%
  mutate( daily_temp = as.numeric( daily_temp ) ) %>%
  mutate( mean_monthly = as.numeric( mean_monthly ) ) %>%
  mutate( delta_temp = ( daily_temp - mean_monthly ) / mean_monthly ) %>%

  # Here I add the difference in degrees between daily temp and monthly avg temp
  mutate( temp_dif = daily_temp - mean_monthly)

# For each location, what are some stats about those temp_dif values?
df.loc.stats <-
  df.combo %>% 
  group_by(location) %>%
  summarize(mean_dif = mean(temp_dif),
            mean_abs_dif = mean(abs(temp_dif)),
            SD_dif = sd(temp_dif))
```

The `df.loc.stats` table shows that location B had the most varied temperatures (measured either using mean absolute difference or standard deviation, for example), while A was lowest under avg temp and C was highest:

```
df.loc.stats
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  location mean_dif mean_abs_dif SD_dif
  <chr>       <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A            -1.8          1.8   1.79
2 B            -1.2          2.8   3.70
3 C             1            1.8   2.24
```